# Mixing Thrust and cuBLAS unexpected results in output

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, cublas

I love thrust library, especially how it nicely hides complexity of cudaMalloc, cudaFree etc.. .

I want to sum all the columns of a matrix. So I used cuBlas's "cublasSgemv" and multiple my matrix by a vector of ones. Here is my code:

```
void sEarColSum(std::vector<float>& inMatrix, int colSize)
{
    cublasHandle_t handle; // CUBLAS context
    float al = 1.0f; // al =1
    float bet = 1.0f; // bet =1
    int rowSize = inMatrix.size() / colSize;

    float *devOutputPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(thrust::device_malloc<float>(colSize));

    thrust::device_vector<float> deviceT2DMatrix(inMatrix.begin(), inMatrix.end());
    float* device2DMatrixPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(deviceT2DMatrix.data());

    thrust::device_vector<float> deviceVector(rowSize, 1.0f);
    float* deviceVecPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(deviceVector.data());

    cublasCreate(&handle);
    cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, colSize, rowSize, &al, device2DMatrixPtr, colSize, deviceVecPtr, 1, &bet, devOutputPtr, 1);

    std::vector<float> outputVec(colSize);
    cudaMemcpy(outputVec.data(), devOutputPtr, outputVec.size() * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (auto elem : outputVec)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}



int main(void)
{
    std::vector < float > temp(100, 1); // A vector of 100 elements each 1 
    sEarColSum( temp, 10 ); // Means my vector will have 10 columns and 100/10 = 10 rows  
  //so I expect a output vector with 10 elements. Which all elements have the value of 10. 
}
```

Unfortunately result are just garbage. I were expecting a vector of ten elements with each value is ten. But instead what I get is :

```
30
30
-2.80392e+036
30
30
-4.95176e+029
30
6.64319e+016
-3.72391e+037
30
```

Am I missing anything, where did my code went wrong?
And secondly is there anyway to check forexample "float* device2DMatrixPtr" with debugger? Visual studio shows its adress but since it is in GPU memory it does not show the data inside of the adress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cublas function `gemv` does a [matrix-vector product](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemv):

```
y = alpha*A*x + beta*y
```

The `y` in your above equation is represented by your `devOutputPtr` which you are allocating like this:

```
float *devOutputPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(thrust::device_malloc<float>(colSize));
```

Ordinary thrust allocations like this:

```
thrust::device_vector<float> my_vec...
```

will allocate *and initialize* the storage, but `thrust::device_malloc` only allocates the storage, it does not initialize it.

Therefore your `y` "vector" initially contains garbage.  If you had set your `beta` to zero, then it would not matter.  But since your `beta` is set to 1, the contents of this uninitialized area are added to your result vector.

If you set

```
float bet = 0.0f;
```

I think you'll get the expected results  (I do, with that change.)

Regarding this question:

> And secondly is there anyway to check forexample "float* device2DMatrixPtr" with debugger?

You can just print the `deviceT2DMatrix` values out using e.g. `printf` or `std::cout`.  Thrust will copy the values device->host "under the hood" for you, to facilitate that.  If you want to access the device copies in the debugger, use the device-debug capability of nsight VSE on windows, or nsight EE or cuda-gdb on linux

Comment: Thank you !!!! One thing I don't understand , if memory allocation is that much simple with thrust, why would anyone still use cublasSetMatrix which take 6 parameters?

Comment: `cublasSetMatrix` doesn't [do allocation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublassetmatrix).  And if you're claiming (which you seem to be, in your question) that this: `float *devOutputPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(thrust::device_malloc<float>(colSize));` is simpler than this: `float *devOutputPtr; cudaMalloc(&devOutputPtr, colSize*sizeof(float));`, well, I'm not sure I agree with you.

Comment: Again thanks for commenting, What I am comparing is   `thrust::device_vector<float> deviceT2DMatrix(inMatrix.begin(), inMatrix.end());
 float* device2DMatrixPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(deviceT2DMatrix.data());` vs         `float * device2DMatrixPtr;
 cublasSetMatrix(rowSize, colSize, sizeof(float)*inMatrix.size(), inMatrix.data(), rowSize, device2DMatrixPtr, rowSize);`

Comment: I guess you still really don't understand that `cublasSetMatrix` doesn't do allocation.  Therefore  your second example **could not work** as written.  This seems to be wildly off-track from your original question.  If you think it's an important question to ask "why would anyone use cublasSetMatrix" please ask it as a new question.

Comment: Definitely I didn't typed this cudaMalloc because of char limitation, it makes the second syntax longer and that is what I don't like. First way  seems to me shorter. Anyways it seems it is not very important, I will keep it to myself. Thanks a lot

Comment: from a *copying* perspective, `cublasSetMatrix` can do things that thrust can't, such as set/modify a sub-matrix within a larger matrix that is already on the device.